# How am I supposed to know when to stop receiving user inputs in C?

Tags: c

This is the task given:

> Write a program that encrypts the text from the input by using an easy
> substitution method. The only allowed characters in input are letters
> 'A'-'Z', whitespace and a newline character. What is a substitution
> method using ciphertext alphabet? It is easy, let us follow the
> example:
>
> Standard English alphabet:    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
>  Ciphertext
> alphabet:     ZEBRASCDFGHIJKLMNOPQTUVWXY
>
> Text to be encrypted:
>
> BEST
>  UNIVERSITY FOR YOU
>
> We replace each letter from the input text with the appropriate letter
> from ciphertext, e.g., A is replaced with Z, B is replaced with E, C
> is replaced with B, and, e.g.,  M is replaced ith J, etc. Thus, we
> get:
>
> EAPQ
>  TKFUAOPFQX SLO XLT
>
> So, Input consists of two parts, in the first line there is a
> ciphertext, that is a string of length 26 consisting of non-repeating
> letters 'A','B',...,'Z' (English 26 letters), in some order. In the
> second part of the input, i.e., in the successive lines, there is a
> text consisting of letters ('A'-'Z'), whitespace and a newline
> character.
>
> You have to print enciphered input text, as follows: each letter from
> input substitute with the appropriate letter from the ciphertext,
> leaving whitespaces and newline characters.
>
> Example:
>
> Input:
>
> ZEBRASCDFGHIJKLMNOPQTUVWXY
>  FLEE AT ONCE WE ARE DISCOVERED
> FLEE AT ONCE WE ARE DISCOVERED
>
> Output:
>
> SIAA ZQ LKBA VA ZOA RFPBLUAOAR
>  SIAA ZQ LKBA VA ZOA RFPBLUAOAR

**I have already written the code for encrypting the text. It works as intended, in the beginning I thought I had only two lines of input. When I submit it like that, I get an unspecified error.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
int i, len1, len2, j;
char toenc1[40], toenc2[40], enc[27], alph[27] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
fgets(enc, 40, stdin); 
fgets(toenc1, 40, stdin); 
fgets(toenc2, 40, stdin); 
len1 = strlen(toenc1); // 
len2 = strlen(toenc2);
for (i = 0 ; i < len1 ; i ++){
    for (j = 0; j < 27 ; j++){
        if (toenc1[i] == alph[j]){
        toenc1[i] = enc[j]; 
        j=26;
        }
    }
}
for (i = 0 ; i < len2 ; i ++){
    for (j = 0; j < 27 ; j++){
        if (toenc2[i] == alph[j]){
        toenc2[i] = enc[j]; 
        j=26;
        }
    }
}
printf("%s", toenc1);
printf("%s", toenc2);
return 0;
}
```

**In the second part of the input, i.e., in the successive lines** is what caught me off-guard. I don't know how to deal with this part.

Comment: Check return value of `fgets` (or any other inout reading function you may use). I mean, read the docs on what yhe return values mean.

Comment: As a good practice I suggest you to use proper indentation and to adopt function to separate the behaviour/logic and to make the code more readable

Comment: If the first input is the key, and subsequent inputs are the messages to be encoded: `while(fgets(msg, sizeof msg, stdin) != NULL) { /* encypher the message */ }`. But make the input buffer size *much* bigger than the expected input, unless that has been specified. Never be mean with your buffer sizes unless memory usage is at a real premium.

Answer (score 1):

> **In the second part of the input, i.e., in the successive lines** is what caught me off-guard. I don't know how to deal with this part.

Presumably, the concept you are struggling with is that there might be a limited number of successive lines.  Nevertheless, it is true, just as much when the program is reading from its standard input as when it reading from a file on disk (and indeed, the standard input might *be* from a file on disk).  Surely you recognize that a disk file has a fixed length, so if you keep reading from it then eventually you will reach the end.

Having accepted that you can read the input to its end, at least in principle, the easier part is finding out how to detect when you have in fact gotten there.  That's easier, because you can just read the documentation of your chosen input function (`fgets()` in this case) to find out what it does under those circumstances.  For example, [its manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) says, in part:

> `gets()` and `fgets()` return [...] NULL on error or when end of file occurs while no characters have been read.

That tells you what you need to know to solve the problem.  And it also tells you something you need to know to write robust code that uses `fgets()` in less controlled environments, where the input might not always have the form you expect.